# Web.config Combining authorization rules

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have the following authorization rules in my web.config:

```
<location path="Register.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="ForgotCredentials.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Except for the path attribute these two rules are the same. Is there a way to combine these two rules into one like path = Register.aspx, ForgotCredentials.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. That `path` property just accepts one file/directory at time.

Also consider this documents:

- [`<location>` path attribute in web.config doesn't accept multiple paths](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=104010)
- [location Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to place them in a common folder which held the rules for all sub-files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way.  You have to specify multiple location elements unfortunately.